# Nested Dictionary in Python 3.7 with list init

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary which contains  data for exchange points

```
points = {
    1:{'name': 'ТОО ARS', 'address': 'str. 10А', 'rates': [{'currency': 'No Data', 'bid': 'No Data', 'ask': 'No Data'}], 'lat': 43.215702, 'lng': 76.860278, 'distance': 459, 'point_id': 10},
    2:{'name': 'ТОО REAL EXCHANGE', 'address': 'ave. 10', 'rates': [{'currency': 'EUR', 'bid': 519.3, 'ask': 521.2}], 'lat': 43.218291, 'lng': 76.866234, 'distance': 915, 'point_id': 8},
    3:{'name': 'ТОО REAL EXCHANGE', 'address': 'ave. 10', 'rates': [{'currency': 'USD', 'bid': 430.0, 'ask': 432.0}], 'lat': 43.218291, 'lng': 76.866234, 'distance': 915, 'point_id': 8},
    4:{'name': 'ТОО REAL EXCHANGE', 'address': 'ave. 10', 'rates': [{'currency': 'TRY', 'bid': 86.0, 'ask': 88.0}], 'lat': 43.218291, 'lng': 76.866234, 'distance': 915, 'point_id': 8},
    5:{'name': 'ТОО REAL EXCHANGE', 'address': 'ave. 10', 'rates': [{'currency': 'KGS', 'bid': 6.0, 'ask': 8.0}], 'lat': 43.218291, 'lng': 76.866234, 'distance': 915, 'point_id': 8},
    6:{'name': 'ТОО ARS', 'address': 'str. 10А', 'rates':  [{'currency': 'KGS-2', 'bid': 6.0, 'ask': 8.0}], 'lat': 43.215702, 'lng': 76.860278, 'distance': 360, 'point_id': 10},
}
```

how do I can get new dictionary like

```
new_dict = {10: {'name': 'ТОО ARS',
  'address': 'str. 10А',
  'rates': [{'currency': 'No Data', 'bid': 'No Data', 'ask': 'No Data'},{'currency': 'KGS-2', 'bid': 6.0, 'ask': 8.0}]},
 8: {'name': 'ТОО REAL EXCHANGE',
  'address': 'ave. 10',
  'rates': [{'currency': 'EUR', 'bid': 519.3, 'ask': 521.2},
   {'currency': 'USD', 'bid': 430.0, 'ask': 432.0},
   {'currency': 'TRY', 'bid': 86.0, 'ask': 88.0},
   {'currency': 'KGS', 'bid': 6.0, 'ask': 8.0}]}}
```

I've tried like

```
points = {
    1:{'name': 'ТОО ARS', 'address': 'str. 10А', 'rates': [{'currency': 'No Data', 'bid': 'No Data', 'ask': 'No Data'}], 'lat': 43.215702, 'lng': 76.860278, 'distance': 459, 'point_id': 10},
    2:{'name': 'ТОО REAL EXCHANGE', 'address': 'ave. 10', 'rates': [{'currency': 'EUR', 'bid': 519.3, 'ask': 521.2}], 'lat': 43.218291, 'lng': 76.866234, 'distance': 915, 'point_id': 8},
    3:{'name': 'ТОО REAL EXCHANGE', 'address': 'ave. 10', 'rates': [{'currency': 'USD', 'bid': 430.0, 'ask': 432.0}], 'lat': 43.218291, 'lng': 76.866234, 'distance': 915, 'point_id': 8},
    4:{'name': 'ТОО REAL EXCHANGE', 'address': 'ave. 10', 'rates': [{'currency': 'TRY', 'bid': 86.0, 'ask': 88.0}], 'lat': 43.218291, 'lng': 76.866234, 'distance': 915, 'point_id': 8},
    5:{'name': 'ТОО REAL EXCHANGE', 'address': 'ave. 10', 'rates': [{'currency': 'KGS', 'bid': 6.0, 'ask': 8.0}], 'lat': 43.218291, 'lng': 76.866234, 'distance': 915, 'point_id': 8},
    6:{'name': 'ТОО ARS', 'address': 'str. 10А', 'rates':  [{'currency': 'KGS-2', 'bid': 6.0, 'ask': 8.0}], 'lat': 43.215702, 'lng': 76.860278, 'distance': 360, 'point_id': 10},
}
new_dict={}

test_keys=[]

z=0

rates=[]

for i in points:
    test_keys.append(points[i]['point_id'])
    for key in range(len(test_keys)-1):
        if test_keys[key+1] == test_keys[key]:
            test_keys.remove(test_keys[key+1])

for keys in test_keys:
    new_dict[keys] = ''

for i in new_dict:
    for j in points:
        if i == points[j]['point_id']:
            name = points[j]['name']
            address = points[j]['address']
            new_dict[i] = {'name':points[j]['name'], 'address':address, 'rates': rates}

for i in range(1,len(points)):
    if points[i]['point_id'] in new_dict:
        kurs = points[i]['rates'][0]
        exchange_point_id = points[i]['point_id']
        for j in new_dict.keys():
            if exchange_point_id == j:
                z+=1
                if z>1:
                    rates.append(kurs)
                    new_dict[j]['rates'] = rates
                elif z<=1:
                    new_dict[j]['rates'] = kurs
```

and it doesn't work

the result I get is:

```
{10: {'name': 'ТОО ARS',
  'address': 'str. 10А',
  'rates': {'currency': 'No Data', 'bid': 'No Data', 'ask': 'No Data'}},
 8: {'name': 'ТОО REAL EXCHANGE',
  'address': 'ave. 10',
  'rates': [{'currency': 'EUR', 'bid': 519.3, 'ask': 521.2},
   {'currency': 'USD', 'bid': 430.0, 'ask': 432.0},
   {'currency': 'TRY', 'bid': 86.0, 'ask': 88.0},
   {'currency': 'KGS', 'bid': 6.0, 'ask': 8.0}]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just want to group elements with the same point_id?

```
from pprint import pprint

points = {
    1:{'name': 'ТОО ARS', 'address': 'str. 10А', 'rates': [{'currency': 'No Data', 'bid': 'No Data', 'ask': 'No Data'}], 'lat': 43.215702, 'lng': 76.860278, 'distance': 459, 'point_id': 10},
    2:{'name': 'ТОО REAL EXCHANGE', 'address': 'ave. 10', 'rates': [{'currency': 'EUR', 'bid': 519.3, 'ask': 521.2}], 'lat': 43.218291, 'lng': 76.866234, 'distance': 915, 'point_id': 8},
    3:{'name': 'ТОО REAL EXCHANGE', 'address': 'ave. 10', 'rates': [{'currency': 'USD', 'bid': 430.0, 'ask': 432.0}], 'lat': 43.218291, 'lng': 76.866234, 'distance': 915, 'point_id': 8},
    4:{'name': 'ТОО REAL EXCHANGE', 'address': 'ave. 10', 'rates': [{'currency': 'TRY', 'bid': 86.0, 'ask': 88.0}], 'lat': 43.218291, 'lng': 76.866234, 'distance': 915, 'point_id': 8},
    5:{'name': 'ТОО REAL EXCHANGE', 'address': 'ave. 10', 'rates': [{'currency': 'KGS', 'bid': 6.0, 'ask': 8.0}], 'lat': 43.218291, 'lng': 76.866234, 'distance': 915, 'point_id': 8},
    6:{'name': 'ТОО ARS', 'address': 'str. 10А', 'rates':  [{'currency': 'KGS-2', 'bid': 6.0, 'ask': 8.0}], 'lat': 43.215702, 'lng': 76.860278, 'distance': 360, 'point_id': 10},
}

new_dict = {}
for point in points.values():
    point_id = point["point_id"]
    if point_id in new_dict:
        new_dict[point_id]["rates"].extend(point["rates"])
    else:
        new_dict[point_id] = point.copy()
        new_dict[point_id].pop("point_id")

pprint(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{8: {'address': 'ave. 10',
     'distance': 915,
     'lat': 43.218291,
     'lng': 76.866234,
     'name': 'ТОО REAL EXCHANGE',
     'rates': [{'ask': 521.2, 'bid': 519.3, 'currency': 'EUR'},
               {'ask': 432.0, 'bid': 430.0, 'currency': 'USD'},
               {'ask': 88.0, 'bid': 86.0, 'currency': 'TRY'},
               {'ask': 8.0, 'bid': 6.0, 'currency': 'KGS'}]},
 10: {'address': 'str. 10А',
      'distance': 459,
      'lat': 43.215702,
      'lng': 76.860278,
      'name': 'ТОО ARS',
      'rates': [{'ask': 'No Data', 'bid': 'No Data', 'currency': 'No Data'},
                {'ask': 8.0, 'bid': 6.0, 'currency': 'KGS-2'}]}}
```

Comment: Oh thank you for your comment. In fact I would like to group rates element with same point_id. yes